# Gem Not Found, Even After Bundling

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm, bundler

I have the gem specificed in my Gemfile, installing from a Github repo:

```
gem 'surveygizmo', :git => 'git://github.com/ample/surveygizmo.git'
```

When I do bundle update, included in the list, I see:

```
Using surveygizmo (0.0.1) from git://github.com/ample/surveygizmo.git (at master)
```

But when attempting to start my sinatra app (using 'ruby go.rb'), it says it can't find surveygizmo:

```
/Users/jeff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- surveygizmo (LoadError)
```

**... but I don't understand why.** By everything I've seen, it's installing. But then it says it's not. Any idea why>

I've pulled at straws all day and am completely lost. I see "1.9.1" in the error, but RVM is pointed at 1.9.3. 'RVM list' displays this:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p357 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
```

[edit]: it's not showing when I do `gem list`

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
activesupport (3.2.8)
addressable (2.3.2)
bundler (1.1.5 ruby)
...(others)....
rake (0.9.2)
shotgun (0.9)
simple_oauth (0.1.9)
sinatra (1.3.3)
thin (1.4.1)
```

Comment: did you run the command gem list ? can you see the gem listed?

Comment: It is not listed when I do gem list. Why would it say it's being installed, and then not appear in the gem list?

Comment: try this: gem install surveygizmo

Comment: Installing the gem manually using "gem install surveygizmo" let me start the server, but it's not installing the correct gem. I need to install the gem from a github repo, not rubygems. There is a similarly named gem on rubygems that's out of date. Can you install a gem this way from a github repo?

Comment: ok, I got it.. gem install surveygizmo --source http://gems.github.com

Comment: make sure to add the http : // gems.github.com

Comment: Alright, so the -l installed a surveygizmo gem from github... but it installed an old version! I'm seeing that github "no longer builds gems". Could this be outdated?

Comment: what version do you need? the only version that I found is the 0.0.1

Comment: Doesn't look like they updated the version number when they merged in the latest changes. Think that could be part of the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.. look at this: https://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct that could be the reason... honestly I always use rubygems. Maybe you could find more documentation about the gem you want and the current version or if it's outdated and others gems to replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix your command:

```
bundle exec ruby go.rb
```

This will ensure bundler is loaded and all **Bundler** gems will be available, especially the `:git` gems.

Comment: Sure enough, adding `bundle exec` did the trick - thanks! Is this a Sinatra situation? I've never had to do this with a Rails app before.